# Почему register_next_step_handler не записывает сообщение пользователя отправленное боту?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, vkontakte-api, telebot

Есть бот (часть кода представлена ниже), он должен получать ссылку на пользователя вк и возращать его имя и фамалию, ссылка в свою очередь должна храниться в переменной text, которая передается в функцию для получения имени и фамилии. Подскажите пожалуйста!

```
def vk(msg):
    name = session.method("users.get", {"user_id": msg})
    firstname = name[0]['first_name']
    send_mess = "Имя: "
    bot.send_message(msg.chat_id ,send_mess, firstname)

def queryHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query=update.callback_query.data
    update.callback_query.answer()
    if "vk" in query:
        text = bot.send_message(chat_id= update.effective_chat.id, text="Отправь ссылку")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(text, vk(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` хранит не текст ответа от пользователя, а объект `message`, поэтому в методе `vk`  вам надо достать из `message` текст и затем сделать запрос к api vk

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как достать из `message` сам текст, вы имеете ввиду `msg.text`?

Comment: Да, так, `msg.text`

Comment: `name = session.method("users.get", {"user_id": msg.text})` в этом случае текст вытаскивать или тут `bot.register_next_step_handler(text, vk(msg.text))`?

Comment: Это всегда можно проверить, запустив код, а так в первом

Comment: Я пробовал менять в обоих случаях и все равно не работает, причем при вводе ссылки, функция `vk` учитывает только короткое имя или числа из самого id, но даже если ввожу эти данные, то он не видит их, я написал тестовый код, но без подключения телеграм апи и на консоль у меня выводилось имя и фамилия при вводе короткого имени

Comment: У меня есть код бота, в котором тоже были `register_next_step_handler` Можете здесь посмотреть логику того, как работает регистрация события и извлечение ответа https://github.com/Apsadikov/bot/blob/master/main.py с 208 строки смотрите

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас пойду разбираться!